# Form-based JAAS authentication: Log-in on index.xhtml and stay on index.xhtml

Tags: jboss, jaas

*I guess that this question has been answered somewhere before, but googleing for jaas and form-based authentication does not help:*

I would like to use JAAS in my JSF application, because I like the idea that you can change the login module from Database to Ldap without changing the application.

However, the `web.xml` login-config seems to be limited to `BASIC`, `CLIENT-CERT`, `FORM`, etc., and I don't want to use any of those. Form-based authentication seems close to what I need, but I do not have a strict separation between public and restricted pages.

**I just want the user to be able to (*optionally*) log-in on `index.xhtml` but stay on `index.xhtml` without any redirection.**

How can I authenticate with JAAS using an HTML form without having a `<url-pattern>` constraint in `web.xml`?

P.S.: In case it is relevant: I'm using JBoss AS 7.1. and JSF 2